# Make third party browser as default

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me how can we make our browser as default in Android? I want to do so that
when you open up the internet browser, it gives you two options: regular browser and Mybrowser (third party browser which is made by me). If you select the regular browser, it says that the phone cannot access the internet unless it is on the Mybrowser. Can we implement this feature, and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set this in your AndroidManifest.xml for your activity:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: hi sir..thanks for ur ans..as i put this in my manifest file..default browser is not working..but there is one more small problem that as i click on browser it is not prompting me as i write in my question...can u help me a little more..

Comment: do you have any other browsers than the system's browser? try to do the following: go into settings / applications / default browser / click button "clear defaults"

Comment: hi sir ....no i dont have another browser..i m really not understanding why intent resolver is not working for my activity as i set intent filter as u told me..Plz help me for this